# 'File Outline' feature from Overleaf in TexShop?

Tags: texshop

Working on a large document in TexShop and would love to avoid scrolling.. 'File Outline' in Overleaf shows you a list of your \section etc. and lets you jump to them in the command line by clicking (very nice feature). Anything like this in TexShop? Haven't found through google. Thanks!

Edit: 'Tags' menu for drop-down list. Unable to see tags as window or access 'Tags' list with keyboard shortcut

Comment: See the Tags menu at the top of the editor window.

Comment: Thank you! This is great. Any way to see this list as a separate window?